Von Neumann entropy vs Shannon entropy
Let us consider a mixture of quantum states
$$
\rho = \sum p_{i}\left\vert \psi_i\right\rangle \left\langle\psi_i\right\vert\quad
\mbox{probability distribution}\,\,\, p_{i}
$$
If the $\psi_{i}$ form an orthonormal basis, then the density matrix is diagonal
$$
\rho = \operatorname{diag}\left(p_{1}\ldots p_{n}\right)
$$
in this basis, and thus Von Neumann entropy
$$
-\operatorname{Tr}\left(\rho\ln\left(\rho\right)\right) = -\sum p_{i}\ln\left(p_{i}\right)
$$
equals to the Shannon entropy of the probability distribution $p_{i}$ in this case.
What happens if the set $\left\vert\psi_{i}\right\rangle$ is not orthogonal, normalised, or even form a basis ?. Do we still have this equality ?.
EDIT : as it appears that the general answer is no, let me rephrase : do we have general theorems, maybe inequalities, between thos two entropies?

The simplest quantum states you can take are qubits which are just vectors in $\mathbb C^2,.$ Take two of them and see what you get. You can do all calculations explicitly with linear algebra methods.

The answer is no. On the other hand, given ρ you can always find $p$'s and an orthonormal basis as you have, and for them the answer will be yes (just as you write).

Short answer : no.
Initially, the (Shannon) entropy is defined as the quantity $S = -\sum_k p_k\ln p_k$, with $p_k$ being the eigenvalues of the density matrix $\hat{\rho}$. This expression can be recasted as the trace of a diagonal matrix $D = \operatorname{diag}(\ldots, p_k\ln p_k, \ldots)$, which is nothing else than the diagonalized version of the operator $\hat{\rho}\ln\hat{\rho}$. Since $\hat{\rho}$ is hermitian, the spectral theorem implies that it is always diagonalizable with the help of a unitary matrix. And given that the trace is invariant under a unitary change of basis, we are allowed to write $S = -\operatorname{tr}D = -\operatorname{tr}(\hat{\rho}\ln\hat{\rho})$, the latter expression corresponding to the von Neumann entropy. In the end, there are not two notions of entropy but two formulations of the same concept.
Now, the density matrix has to be expressed with respect to a given basis. Note that a non-complete set of kets $|\psi_k\rangle$, as you suggest, doesn't really make sense, because it would imply to work in a subspace of the Hilbert space only $-$ even if it is sometimes considered when computing partial traces.
The projection of $\hat{\rho}$ over a general basis $\{|e_k\rangle\}_k$ is given by $\hat{\rho} = \sum_{i,j} \rho_{ij} |e_i\rangle\langle e_j|$, where $\rho_{ij}$ are mere components and cannot be interpreted as probabilities such as $p_i$. The case where the basis vectors aren't normalized isn't very interesting actually, because their norms can "compensated" by renormalization of the components $\rho_{ij}$, that is why we consider normalized kets conventionally.
Finally, a non-orthogonal basis is not a great deal, because the "overlapping components" will be taken into accounts through the inner products with the orthonormal basis $|\phi_k\rangle\}_k$ with respect to which the trace to which the trace is computed, as done below :
$$
\operatorname{tr}\hat{\rho}\ln\hat{\rho} 
   = \sum_k \langle\phi_k|\hat{\rho}\ln\hat{\rho}|\phi_k\rangle 
   = \sum_{i,j,k} a_{ij} \langle\phi_k|e_i\rangle \langle e_j|\phi_k\rangle
$$
where $a_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-component associated to $\hat{\rho}\ln\hat{\rho}$, which may be a quite nasty expression mixing up all the component $\rho_{ij}$ because of the logarithm.
In the end, here is the keypoint : the basis used to compute the trace, denoted by $\{|\phi_k\rangle\}_k$ here, must be orthonormal, because a non-unitary change of basis will affect the result, while the basis $\{|e_k\rangle\}_k$ needn't. However, since $\hat{\rho}$ is hermitian and thus unitarily diagonalizable, the natural choice is $|e_k\rangle = |\phi_k\rangle = |\psi_k\rangle$, with $\{|\psi_k\rangle\}_k$ being the eigenbasis of the density matrix. And it allows to match its components with its eigenvalues, interpreted as probabilities in a Shannon point of view, at the same time.

The important thing to realize here is that the entropy of a state depends only on the eigenvalues. The eigenbasis plays no part in the definition. This point should maybe more often be stressed. The entropy of a quantum state $\rho$ is defined as the Shannon entropy of the probability distribution defined by its eigenvalues. Observe that since a state is a posivitive matrix, all the eigenvalues are non-negative real numbers. Since it has unit trace, the eigenvalues sum to one, so this makes perfect sense.
